# Iterating over a dict made from a .CSV

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a .CSV file that looks like this:

```
NAME            ES  VALUE FILE_LOC                                     NOTES
android_female  HAPPY   25  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_happy_25.obj   Slightly happy
android_female  HAPPY   50  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_happy_50.obj   happy
android_female  HAPPY   75  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_happy_75.obj   Joyful or glee, eyes squinty
android_female  SAD 25  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_sad_25.obj Morose
android_female  SAD 75  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_sad_75.obj Very Sad
android_female  CONFUSED    50  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_confused_50.obj    Bewildered
android_female  SCARED  50  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_scared_50.obj  Frightened
android_female  TIRED   25  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_tired_25.obj   Slightly run down
android_female  TIRED   75  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_tired_75.obj   Very tired
android_female  SURPRISED   50  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_surprised_50.obj   Semi shocked
android_female  EMBARRASSED 50  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_embarrassed_50.obj Reddened cheeks
android_female  KISS    50  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_kiss_50.obj    Kissy face, eyes closed
android_female  MISCHIEVOUS 50  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_mischievous_50.obj Smirking and shifty eyes
 android_female PAIN    25  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_pain_25.obj    Slight pain, grimace
android_female  PAIN    75  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_pain_75.obj    Severe pain, eyes closed
android_female  ANGRY   25  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_angry_25.obj   Upset, brow furrowed
android_female  ANGRY   75  C:\Users\jason\Documents\3Dobjects\poses\androidfemale\androidfemale_angry_75.obj   Very angry, brows down
```

Fairly simple.  To get it from .CSV into a dict, I have the following code:

```
layouts_schema_file_name ='C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\RAY\\char_es_schemas\\ANIBOT_CHAR_ES_SCHEMA.csv'
full_path_to_file = layouts_schema_file_name 
print('============ Importing LAYOUTS schema from: ', full_path_to_file , ' ==============')
openfile = open(full_path_to_file)
reader = csv.DictReader(openfile)

print('Printing Character Emotional States reader file:')
print(reader)

char_es_schema = {}

for group1, records1 in itertools.groupby(reader, key=operator.itemgetter("NAME")):
    char_es_schema[group1] = {}
    for group2, records2 in itertools.groupby(records1, key=operator.itemgetter("ES")):
        char_es_schema[group1][group2] = list(records2)
        #for group3, records3 in itertools.groupby(records2, key=operator.itemgetter("VALUE")):  
        #   char_es_schema[group2][group3] = list(records3)
```

This results in the following (probably too complicated) dict, which is intended to store the keys and values in a structured way:

```
{'android_female': {'ANGRY': [{'ES': 'ANGRY',
                           'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_angry_25.obj',
                           'NAME': 'android_female',
                           'NOTES': 'Upset, brow furrowed',
                           'VALUE': '25'},
                          {'ES': 'ANGRY',
                           'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_angry_75.obj',
                           'NAME': 'android_female',
                           'NOTES': 'Very angry, brows down',
                           'VALUE': '75'}],
                'CONFUSED': [{'ES': 'CONFUSED',
                              'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_confused_50.obj',
                              'NAME': 'android_female',
                              'NOTES': 'Bewildered',
                              'VALUE': '50'}],
                'EMBARRASSED': [{'ES': 'EMBARRASSED',
                                 'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_embarrassed_50.obj',
                                 'NAME': 'android_female',
                                 'NOTES': 'Reddened cheeks',
                                 'VALUE': '50'}],
                'HAPPY': [{'ES': 'HAPPY',
                           'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_happy_25.obj',
                           'NAME': 'android_female',
                           'NOTES': 'Slightly happy',
                           'VALUE': '25'},
                          {'ES': 'HAPPY',
                           'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_happy_50.obj',
                           'NAME': 'android_female',
                           'NOTES': 'happy',
                           'VALUE': '50'},
                          {'ES': 'HAPPY',
                           'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_happy_75.obj',
                           'NAME': 'android_female',
                           'NOTES': 'Joyful or glee, eyes squinty',
                           'VALUE': '75'}],
                'KISS': [{'ES': 'KISS',
                          'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_kiss_50.obj',
                          'NAME': 'android_female',
                          'NOTES': 'Kissy face, eyes closed',
                          'VALUE': '50'}],
                'MISCHIEVOUS': [{'ES': 'MISCHIEVOUS',
                                 'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_mischievous_50.obj',
                                 'NAME': 'android_female',
                                 'NOTES': 'Smirking and shifty eyes',
                                 'VALUE': '50'}],
                'PAIN': [{'ES': 'PAIN',
                          'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_pain_25.obj',
                          'NAME': 'android_female',
                          'NOTES': 'Slight pain, grimace',
                          'VALUE': '25'},
                         {'ES': 'PAIN',
                          'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_pain_75.obj',
                          'NAME': 'android_female',
                          'NOTES': 'Severe pain, eyes closed',
                          'VALUE': '75'}],
                'SAD': [{'ES': 'SAD',
                         'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_sad_25.obj',
                         'NAME': 'android_female',
                         'NOTES': 'Morose',
                         'VALUE': '25'},
                        {'ES': 'SAD',
                         'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_sad_75.obj',
                         'NAME': 'android_female',
                         'NOTES': 'Very Sad',
                         'VALUE': '75'}],
                'SCARED': [{'ES': 'SCARED',
                            'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_scared_50.obj',
                            'NAME': 'android_female',
                            'NOTES': 'Frightened',
                            'VALUE': '50'}],
                'SURPRISED': [{'ES': 'SURPRISED',
                               'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_surprised_50.obj',
                               'NAME': 'android_female',
                               'NOTES': 'Semi shocked',
                               'VALUE': '50'}],
                'TIRED': [{'ES': 'TIRED',
                           'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_tired_25.obj',
                           'NAME': 'android_female',
                           'NOTES': 'Slightly run down',
                           'VALUE': '25'},
                          {'ES': 'TIRED',
                           'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_tired_75.obj',
                           'NAME': 'android_female',
                           'NOTES': 'Very tired',
                           'VALUE': '75'}]}}
```

I'm trying to iterate over this nested dict in order to match up the NAME and ES levels and the VALUE in the last level (it's actually a list with a dict in it).  The intention is to simple pull the file_loc for use later, using NAME, ES and VALUE to pull it.  It's supposed to be a 3 key concatenated field.

Having a hard time doing this multiple ways.  I suspect my dict is overly complicated, would appreciate any thoughts.

Here is my code to iterate which doesn't work now:

```
for actors in char_es_schema.keys():
        if found_it == True:
            print('Found character emotional state...')
            continue
        for emotions in actors:
            for poses in emotions:
                print('Current ES state and value we are searching is: ',char_es_schema[actor_name][curr_es][0]['ES'] ,char_es_schema[actor_name][curr_es][0]['VALUE'])
                if char_es_schema[actor_name][curr_es][0]['VALUE'] == curr_es_level:
                    file_loc = char_es_schema[actor_name][curr_es][0]['FILE_LOC']#!!!!!! what code goes here JMR 12/4
                    print('Found file location for emotional state:', curr_es, curr_es_level, ' - : ', file_loc)
                    found_it = True
            if found_it == True:
               -do some stuff-
```

Any ideas?  I think I made my dict too complicate and hard to iterate over, but would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Why have the nested dictionary in the first place?

Comment: Just the way I've parsed it for now.   Would be open to any suggestions.

Comment: If this is your "first shot" at parsing your data, this is probably way over complicated. You should think about your end goal and the shortest path to that goal.  Apply [Occam's Razor](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) to your work and life will be easier.

Comment: Thanks Jon.   I'm new at python and though it's an elegant language, I'm from a SQL background when it comes to parsing data so struggling a bit with dict structure.    My impression is that in making a dict you are making a data structure you can iterate over with for loops and the like.  Still learning, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How 'bout this?

```
def select(schema, name, es, value):                                               
    emotionGrp = schema[name][es]                                                  
    return [x for x in emotionGrp if x['VALUE']==value];                           

print(select(data, 'android_female', 'PAIN', '75'))
```

Where `data` is the data structure you've supplied in your question.

Running this code with your sample data returns:

```
[{'NOTES': 'Severe pain, eyes closed', 'VALUE': '75', 'NAME': 'android_female', 'ES': 'PAIN', 'FILE_LOC': 'C:\\Users\\jason\\Documents\\3Dobjects\\poses\\androidfemale\\androidfemale_pain_75.obj'}]
```

Could be further simplified to just:

```
selectedAndroids = [x for x in schema[name][es] if x['VALUE']==value];
```

What's conspicuously missing is any kind of checking for keys which don't exist in the data model. Hm...

```
selectedAndroids = [x for x in schema.get(name, {}).get(es, {}) if x.get('VALUE', None)==value]
```

Comment: Alternatively (following on from @jon's comment above), you could create a new instance of an 'Android' class from each row of the database and maintain a list of those instances.

Finding a matching android would then be a simple matter of iterating over the list.

Comment: Man that's not a bad idea.   A list of classes.  Very pythonic!  I'll try this, sounds interesting.